# Is there a way to add ports to logic gates dynamically in go.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, logic, nodes, gojs

Im learning sample code from gojs/logic circuit, in that i want to add more ports to logic gates dynamically through context menu or some button, can i do it, i saw dynamic ports example in gojs, but its not working for logic gates, its only working for rectangular box created in that example(dynamic ports), but i want to add more input and out ports to logic gates which are predefined, is that possible ? Im able to add manually by increasing in and out numbers manually in the code(js), but not dynamically, i also want to know is it possible to add 'n' number of ports to predefined logic gates ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The node templates in the Logic Circuit sample each have a fixed number of ports.  For example:

```
      var andTemplate =
        $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
          $(go.Shape, "AndGate", shapeStyle()),
          $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle(true),
            { portId: "in1", alignment: new go.Spot(0, 0.3) }),
          $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle(true),
            { portId: "in2", alignment: new go.Spot(0, 0.7) }),
          $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle(false),
            { portId: "out", alignment: new go.Spot(1, 0.5) })
        );
```

It is possible to add or remove ports from a particular instance of a Node, but is that really what you want?  Adding or removing an element (that happens to be a port) won't modify the model, so when you save and then re-load the model, those changes will have disappeared.

If you want a variable number of ports on a node, you need to define the node template to support a variable number of ports, where the node data object has one or more properties that are Arrays of port descriptor objects.  Each port descriptor would have information about identifier, name, shape, color, position, and perhaps other parameters.

Then there would be one or more Panels whose **Panel.itemArray** is data bound to the corresponding Array property.  The **Panel.itemTemplate** would declare how each item (i.e. port) is visualized.  Please read: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/itemArrays.html

For an example of this with four item Arrays, one for each side of a Node, please examine this sample: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/dynamicPorts.html

That sample also demonstrates various ways in which the user can add or remove or move ports dynamically.

In that sample there is only a single node template, but it's more complex because it supports four separate Arrays of port descriptor objects, one for each side of the Node.  That node template looks like:

```
      myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
        $(go.Node, "Table",
          {
            locationObjectName: "BODY",
            locationSpot: go.Spot.Center,
            selectionObjectName: "BODY",
            contextMenu: nodeMenu
          },
          new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),

          // the body
          $(go.Panel, "Auto",
            {
              row: 1, column: 1, name: "BODY",
              stretch: go.GraphObject.Fill
            },
            $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
              {
                fill: "#dbf6cb", stroke: null, strokeWidth: 0,
                minSize: new go.Size(60, 60)
              }),
            $(go.TextBlock,
              { margin: 10, textAlign: "center", font: "bold 14px Segoe UI,sans-serif", stroke: "#484848", editable: true },
              new go.Binding("text", "name").makeTwoWay())
          ),  // end Auto Panel body

          // the Panel holding the left port elements, which are themselves Panels,
          // created for each item in the itemArray, bound to data.leftArray
          $(go.Panel, "Vertical",
            new go.Binding("itemArray", "leftArray"),
            {
              row: 1, column: 0,
              itemTemplate:
                $(go.Panel,
                  {
                    _side: "left",  // internal property to make it easier to tell which side it's on
                    fromSpot: go.Spot.Left, toSpot: go.Spot.Left,
                    fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true, cursor: "pointer",
                    contextMenu: portMenu
                  },
                  new go.Binding("portId", "portId"),
                  $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
                    {
                      stroke: null, strokeWidth: 0,
                      desiredSize: portSize,
                      margin: new go.Margin(1, 0)
                    },
                    new go.Binding("fill", "portColor"))
                )  // end itemTemplate
            }
          ),  // end Vertical Panel
    ... three more Panels with itemArray Bindings ...
```